# Automatically setting reportViewer page to landscape mode in C#

Tags: c#, printing, report-viewer2010

Is it possible to programmatically set the reportViewers page to landscape mode, so if the user wants to print (preview) it, he doesn't have to change the settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swap the Height and Width of Report Page Size property.